# PHP Trying to Allocate 5,026,248 TB of Memory

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I'm getting this sudden error, and I can't figure our whats going on. I just reloaded the page and it started happening.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5526419083341876096 bytes)
```

For some reason, this piece of code is triggering the error:

```
array('@hash-algos' => implode(', ', hash_algos())))
```

The only thing in the error logs is a repeat of the above error message.

The piece of code is a part of Drupal, and I'm running the latest version. I just edited a CSS file, reloaded, only to be confronted with that error.

I'm running PHP 7 on WampServer on Windows 10 x64

`hash_algos()` on it's own returns the following:

```
array(46) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "md2"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "md4"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "md5"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "sha1"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "sha224"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "sha256"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "sha384"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "sha512"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "ripemd128"
  [9]=>
  string(9) "ripemd160"
  [10]=>
  string(9) "ripemd256"
  [11]=>
  string(9) "ripemd320"
  [12]=>
  string(9) "whirlpool"
  [13]=>
  string(10) "tiger128,3"
  [14]=>
  string(10) "tiger160,3"
  [15]=>
  string(10) "tiger192,3"
  [16]=>
  string(10) "tiger128,4"
  [17]=>
  string(10) "tiger160,4"
  [18]=>
  string(10) "tiger192,4"
  [19]=>
  string(6) "snefru"
  [20]=>
  string(9) "snefru256"
  [21]=>
  string(4) "gost"
  [22]=>
  string(11) "gost-crypto"
  [23]=>
  string(7) "adler32"
  [24]=>
  string(5) "crc32"
  [25]=>
  string(6) "crc32b"
  [26]=>
  string(6) "fnv132"
  [27]=>
  string(7) "fnv1a32"
  [28]=>
  string(6) "fnv164"
  [29]=>
  string(7) "fnv1a64"
  [30]=>
  string(5) "joaat"
  [31]=>
  string(10) "haval128,3"
  [32]=>
  string(10) "haval160,3"
  [33]=>
  string(10) "haval192,3"
  [34]=>
  string(10) "haval224,3"
  [35]=>
  string(10) "haval256,3"
  [36]=>
  string(10) "haval128,4"
  [37]=>
  string(10) "haval160,4"
  [38]=>
  string(10) "haval192,4"
  [39]=>
  string(10) "haval224,4"
  [40]=>
  string(10) "haval256,4"
  [41]=>
  string(10) "haval128,5"
  [42]=>
  string(10) "haval160,5"
  [43]=>
  string(10) "haval192,5"
  [44]=>
  string(10) "haval224,5"
  [45]=>
  string(10) "haval256,5"
}
```

OK, well. This is strange, I restarted the WampServers, and it still happened. But I restarted my computer, and now it has stopped. Maybe something else is causing this? I did install a couple extra PHP extensions, and also a version of memcached for Windows. Perhaps something like that was causing it? I'm not sure, I'm not hugely familiar with how PHP works internally.

Comment: It's unlikely that editing CSS caused this error. How do you known it is this specific line that triggers it?

Comment: So tell us, what does `hash_algos()` return?

Comment: Because all PHP errors tell you the file and line number from which the error originated.

Comment: @Dagon, likely. Look at the error message, it gives the the memory in bytes.